# Displaying Interstitial Advert A 'Fraction Of The Time' - i.e. NOT Every Time

Tags: ios, swift, random, interstitial

A simple question.

I would like an interstitial advert to show a fraction of the time when a user presses a button (executes an IBAction).

I have used the following code:

```
@IBAction func someButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) { 
...
 //Interstitial Ad:

    let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))
    let adNo = 2

    if(adNo == rand)
    {
        loadInterstitialAd()
    }

.... }
```

This should make the interstitial advert show 33% of the time.

Can anyone please let me know if this is correct code? It works in my simulator, I just want to make sure my code is efficient and I'm not breaching any Apple advertising conventions by doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: If your code is working on your simulator, it may be better to just have some beta testers test it at this point.

Comment: Two beta testers came back with all results 100% :-)

Comment: Simple stuff I know. I'm just getting to grips with programming in swift.

Answer (score 0):

I added `print(rand)` in my code and monitored the output window.

Everytime "2" shows, the interstitial advert pops up (albeit slowly at times).

So I guess it works :-)